# What is my cars problem?

Tags: engine, automatic-transmission, nissan, maxima

I have a 2004 Nissan Maxima (168,000 miles). I stopped at a red light, but  I pressed the gas to go again and there was a slight pause before my car began to gain speed and accelerate at a decent pace.

At first, I thought it was my transmission, but even when I floored it my engine didn't roar and my RPM's didn't shoot up. After 3 seconds, the car began to gain speed and behave normally. It repeated that behaviour whenever I took a wide turn or came to a complete stop for that trip. The car is inconsistent in it's behaviour. After getting back in it again a few hours later, it ran as usual.

This has happened three times now, but it does not happen consistently. My oil, coolant and transmission fluids have been topped off.

Comment: It sounds like your car may have gone into some sort of limp mode, do you have any dashboard warning lights or messages?

Comment: My brake and ABS lights are on but that's it.

Comment: Have the codes read and let us know what you find.

Comment: The ABS and brake warnings are unlikely to be related, but you really ought to get them checked out. You're worried about getting your car rolling but you really ought to be worried about it being able to stop.